# Using TcpClient with VPN connection

Tags: tcpclient, vpn

I'm writing a proprietary Telnet class and use TcpClient. Everything works well in the console and data transmission generates no issue with devices (sockets) in the same IP group. I tested also a new WPF project using this class again and the functionality is given as well.

Today I tried the identical WPF project again using a VPN connection, but TcpClient generates an exception. At the beginning it looks like the first console version was still working as expected, but during several tests, I noticed that even the console version generates sporadically an exception.

I checked the VPN connection and the availability of the IP/port. Everything should be fine. I used Wireshark (I’m not familiar with) and it looks like in the case, the connection fails, there is no request to the IP in the VPN network.

After a restart of the computer, connecting seems to work several times, but after a view tests, it ends with an exception again.

For sure, I have to handle the exception but first of all, I try to solve this connection issue.

Did anybody have experience using TcpClient and VPN? I read, that it’s sometimes recommended to use a bind, but till now, I don't have a solution.

[This is a link to the console version I used as a starting point.](http://na.support.keysight.com/fieldfox/help/Programming/webhelp/Examples/CSharp_Example_Program.htm)

Comment: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: "Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat"

Comment: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"